# Aligning buttons in single or double rows based on MaxWidth in XAML

Tags: wpf

I have a XAML layout with a series of buttons within a StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="200">
    <Button Content="1"/>
    <Button Content="2"/>
    <Button Content="3"/>
    <Button Content="4"/>
    <Button Content="5"/>
    <Button Content="6"/>
    <Button Content="7"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My goal is to keep these buttons aligned in a single row as long as the total width does not exceed 200. If the width with all buttons exceeds 200, I would like them to automatically rearrange into two rows, with each row having an even distribution of buttons if possible.
I've attempted to use `UniformGrid` and `WrapPanel` for this layout requirement, but they haven't achieved the desired effect. It's possible I didn't utilize them correctly.

Comment: What behaviour have you noticed using WrapPanel? Usually use that component to get the behaviour you want

Comment: This will not necessarily divide the rows evenly

Comment: You may want to write a [custom Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WrapPanel automatically wraps to a new row when the total width of its children exceeds the specified MaxWidth.
according to this, you can create your WrapPanelCustom and decide precisely when to wrap a new row. For example, in your case :

public class WrapPanelCustom : WrapPanel
{
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
base.OnInitialized(e);
SizeChanged += (_, _) => AdjustRowsBasedOnVisibleChildren();
}

```
private void AdjustRowsBasedOnVisibleChildren()
{
    var totalChildrenWidth = this.FindLogicalChildren<Button>().Sum(c => c.ActualWidth);

    MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;

    // Here is your case condition
    if (totalChildrenWidth > 200)
    {
        MaxWidth = totalChildrenWidth / 2; // achieve two rows
    }
}
```

}

pay attention to the FindLogicalChildren call, I used some generic code like:

public static IEnumerable FindLogicalChildren(this DependencyObject parent) where T: DependencyObject
{
if (parent == null) yield break;

```
 foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent).OfType<DependencyObject>())
 {
     if (child is T t)
     {
         yield return t; 
     }

     foreach (var childOfChild in FindLogicalChildren<T>(child))
     {
         yield return childOfChild;
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As @Yoji has suggested, the wrapping panel should do the job.
Have tested and archived what you have described with following code:

```
  <WrapPanel MaxWidth="200">
      <Button Width="50" Content="1"/>
      <Button Width="50" Content="2"/>
      <Button Width="50" Content="3"/>
      <Button Width="50" Content="4"/>
      <Button Width="50" Content="5"/>
      <Button Width="50" Content="6"/>
      <Button Width="50" Content="7"/>
      <Button Width="50" Content="7"/>
  </WrapPanel>
```

Update:
Based on your description in comments I wrote you a small Control that accodind to my understanding should resolve the issue

```
public class WrapperPanelExtended : WrapPanel
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var itemsCount = InternalChildren.Count;
        var MaxItemsPerColumn = (int)(finalSize.Width / InternalChildren[0].DesiredSize.Width);
        var columntCount = (itemsCount / MaxItemsPerColumn) + 1;
        MaxItemsPerColumn = itemsCount / columntCount;



        for (var i = 0; i < InternalChildren.Count; i++)
        {
            var location = new Point(i % MaxItemsPerColumn * InternalChildren[i].DesiredSize.Width, i / MaxItemsPerColumn * InternalChildren[i].DesiredSize.Height);
            InternalChildren[i].Arrange(new Rect(location, new Size(finalSize.Width, InternalChildren[i].DesiredSize.Height)));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var _ = InternalChildren.Count;

        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
}
```

and in your xaml

```
    <Local:WrapperPanelExtended MaxWidth="200">
        <Button Width="50" Content="1"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="2"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="3"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="4"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="5"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="6"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="7"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="8"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="9"/>
        <Button Width="50" Content="10"/>
    </Local:WrapperPanelExtended>
```

Comment: For instance, changing the MaxWidth to 300 results in two rows, with the first row containing 6 buttons and the second row containing only 2 buttons. However, I'm seeking a solution that ensures an equal divide of buttons across both rows whenever it splits into two rows.

Comment: Are your Button will be the same size? If not, what logic should apply? Have you considered just writing own control, since your case seems to be quite easy to be resolver (you can check example here https://github.com/6demon89/Tutorial.WPF/blob/master/LayoutBasics/Controls/DiagonalPanel.cs)

Comment: Assuming that each button is of uniform size, the solution provided still does not address the issue.

Comment: @OhadCohen Have extended suggested response based on your description. Also it is simple code that you can manipulate into the logic which was not clarified